# How to Create a Table of PDFs with Views?

Tags: 7, views, entities, files

I've been tasked to develop my company's intranet with Drupal. One of the key items is to allow our HR department to upload job openings (PDF's) to display on site. I'm envisioning having this table output using Views but I'm not sure how to set up the front end for the Department to publish the files.

They need to be able to upload a file, give it a name (Job title) & date of upload. Table will then populate with them.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to Drupal.

Regards
Tony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally there would be two steps to this in Drupal 7.

1. Create a content type with the fields you need
2. Create a view to pull in that content

In your content type settings, manage the fields, and you can add a file attachment field (for uploading the PDF) and a text field for entering the job title. Date of upload is automatically created in the sense that your HR people will create a new piece of content (of this new type) when they want to upload a new job opening, and you can use that piece of content's date last edited data for that field. You can enable display of that info in the view settings under Fields.

Once you get your view correctly displaying all the content from your new content type, you can work on styling it as a table with CSS.

Comment: I did try that & got it to work. But was wondering if there was a way to do it without creating a Content Type. Possibly allowing them to upload files & giving them a name. I was testing out File Depot module as doc mgt. tool, but can't seem to get that to work with views.

Comment: Thank you for your help cjl750. I saw that you posted some screen shots yesterday, but they are gone.